# Chrome does not resize SVG image

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, svg

I would like to read in a SVG file, determine its width and height in order to scale it. At the moment, my code looks as follows:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <style type="text/css" media="all">@import "style/style.css";</style>
  <meta name="svg.render.forceflash" content="false" />
  <script src="svg.js" data-path="svgweb/src/"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js">   </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      function loadContent(){
        /*  SVG  */
        var svg = document.getElementById('myimage')

        /*  Adapt size of SVG */
        try {
      SVGDoc = svg.contentDocument;
    } catch (Err) {
      SVGDoc = svg.getSVGDocument;
        }
        var root = SVGDoc.documentElement;
        if (root.attributes['width'] != null) {
        var width = root.attributes['width'].nodeValue;
        width = width.substring(0, width.length - 2);
        width = (width * 1.25);
        var height = root.attributes['height'].nodeValue;
        height = height.substring(0, height.length - 2);
        height = (height * 1.25);
        svg.width = width;
        svg.height = height;
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map">
    <!--[if IE]>
    <object id="myimage" src="images/myimage.svg" classid="image/svg+xml">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]>-->
    <object id="myimage" data="images/myimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    </object>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works fine in Firefox (although one can see for a very short time the resizing). However, the developer tool within Chrome nags: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefined for the line "var root = SVGDoc.documentElement;". In addition, Chrome does not resize the image.

I can't find a working solution for both browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, [getSVGDocument()](http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/1) is a method, not a property. You have to *call* it:

```
SVGDoc = svg.getSVGDocument();
```

Second, `SVGDoc` itself should be declared somewhere:

```
var SVGDoc;
```

Third, Chrome's [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) [does not like](http://www.chromeboard.com/showpost.php?s=957749cef2dd64797b31ca49d8348713&p=73804&postcount=1) the `file:` protocol. You'll have to serve your SVG images instead of reading them from local files.

Comment: Thank you very much for your corrections. However, Chrome still complains about: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rootElement' of undefined

Comment: @labrassbandito, that looks a lot like [Chromium Bug #29296](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=29296). Is your Chrome up-to-date?

Comment: My version is 7.0.517.41 (62167) Ubuntu 10.10. Further on, I read that the error message is only locally while loading the SVG via file://. This seems true, because the code works online as expected. Strange. Unfortunately I missed the website stating this fact. Nonetheless, I am facing the resizing problem. Only in Firefox the SVG resizes automatically.

Comment: `SVGDocument` inherits the `Document` interface, which has `documentElement`. See http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#InterfaceSVGDocument. So there's no problem with calling `documentElement`.

Comment: @Erik, thanks, I wasn't aware of that. The same origin policy also applies to `documentElement`, and what's why we enter the `catch` block in the first place. Answer updated.